# Dynamically computing sample weights as part of Sklearn(Imblearn) pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I want to write Imblearn FunctionTransformer, which would do the following:

1. Remove duplicates from the dataset while compiting duplicate counts.
2. Create duplicate_count field in the dataset and fill this field (or create another dataset for duplicate counts)
3. Return duplicate_count field separately from the dataset.

I want Imblearn pipeline to pass duplicate_count as sample_weight parameter to fit function of the final model.

How do I can perform this?